# CMD.exe quoting a string

Tags: perl, shell, cmd, quote

What's the exact way to *properly* quote a single command line argument?
For example, I have some random text in a variable `$X`. I need to quote it in a way so that if I call

```
system("program.exe " + $X_QUOTED);
```

then `argv[1]` of my program.exe has to match original unquoted `$X`

imagine I have this program.exe:

```
int main(const char **argv, int){ puts(argv[1]); }
```

and the output of command: "program xxxx" is:

```
"test |test
```

what `xxxx` has to literally be? I tried to add quotes and all that trickery, but then I can always add some other type of output that would break my approach to quote cmd line arguments.

Answer (score 2):

```
H:>args """test |test"
argv[0] = args
argv[1] = "test |test
```

Apparently:

- Replace each quote by `""`
- Surround the argument with quotes

Comment: That's the thing. For me it actually prints:
1 : "test
2 : |test

Maybe because I'm using perl in this case and it uses different approach to split commandline?..

Comment: @PPS: You can't. You can edit your original question though, if you need to add something.

Comment: Also I don't know what exactly Perl's `system` command does. I have never used Perl and probably never will.

Comment: At the end it appeared that perl uses some buddy implementation to split command line parameters and that's why I would never be able to get it done properly. It appears that perl that comes with msys is the one that does it properly (and I used activestate or strawberry perl and both of them link to some other runtime that uses some other rules that aren't used on win32)